# Compiling and Running Armadillo with LAPACK/BLAS with Visual Studio 2013: problems when running application in others windows based system

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, armadillo

First, I'm new with programming.

I have already builded a successful solution in my own computer with Visual Studio 2013 with Armadillo and LAPACK/BLAS. I'm able to run both Console Application (*.exe) and (*.dll) in my system (Windows 7).

The problem arrived when I needed to run those application in a different computer with Windows 7. First, every application that i build was throwing the error "MSVCP120D.dll is missing in your computer". I was able to fix this changing "Runtime Library" in VS from MDd(MD) to MTd(MT). With this method I could run a console application with Armadillo, but without the use of LAPACK/BLAS (uncommenting the respective line in config.hpp)

When I enable the use of LAPACK/BLAS with the MTd(MT) Runtime configuration in VS2013, the application no longer run in this different computer.

So, what I'm doing wrong and what to do in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: I've understood the problem. I was using the pre-compiled library lapack_win32_MT.lib and blas_win32_MT.lib. I change it to a newer version avaiable in LAPACK/BLAS site (llapack.lib and lblas.lib) and it's now working.
In case anyone shows up with the same problem.

Comment: I am facing a very similar problem. I am compiling a plug-in with a Library (dll) built with Armadillo. I can run without any trouble locally but not at other users. Could you provide more details about how you solved the issue / the link to download the libraries you mention ? thanks in advance

Comment: To use the app in others computers I had to compile as /MD, it can't be compiled as /MDd. You have to be sure that the updated MS C++ Redistributable package is installed in the user machine. If you use VS 2013, you should install MS Redistributable version 12. The library version that worked was downloaded in http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/ under Prebuilt libraries for Microsoft Visual Studio Projects. In my case I chose win32 dll and win32 lib version of BLAS and LAPACK.

Comment: The downloaded archive name is libblas and liblapack. Putting both *.dll in the app's directory should work. I think those are the key steps.